# Error CS0103: The name '_context' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to connect with a database using Razor pages and Entity Framework but I get this error

> Error CS0103: The name '_context' does not exist in the current context

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using myWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace myWebApp.Pages
{
    public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<EmployeeModel> _logger;

        public EmployeeModel(ILogger<EmployeeModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        // Create
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var emptyreservation = new Reservation();

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Reservation>(
                emptyreservation,
                "reservation",   // Prefix for form value.
                r => r.reservationid, r => r.dayid, r => r.roomid, r => r.employeeid))
            {
                _context.Reservation.Add(emptyreservation);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access dbcontext instance without creating it. (missing a **Dependency Injection**)
add the following to your code and it will work

```
private readonly ILogger<EmployeeModel> _logger;
private YourDbContextName _context

        public EmployeeModel(ILogger<EmployeeModel> logger, YourDbContextName context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context
        }
```

also make sure you have your startup properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it at the top of the class and inject it in the constructor
like that

```
 private readonly ILogger<EmployeeModel> _logger;
  private [YourDbContextName] _context;

    public EmployeeModel(ILogger<EmployeeModel> logger,[YourDbContextName] context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
```

And don't forget to configure Context in the Startup.cs file inside ConfigureServices function

```
var connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:sqlConnection"];

services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

services.AddDbContextPool<DatabaseContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Comment: if he adds private DbContext _context;  it won't work.